# Como alterar a propriedade background-position?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber um javascript que mudava a `background-position` de uma determinada div.

Estou tentando buscar a posiçao do background.

Comment: Posso colocar o valor do tipo 30, 20? dentro de aspas?

Comment: Acredito que não, as propriedades são do tipo: top, left, center, bottom...acredito que valores não sao permitidos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`backgroundPosition`**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundposition.asp):

```js
document.querySelector('div').style.backgroundPosition = '50% 50%';
```

```css
div {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9dbY.jpg) no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Para mudar a posição do background de um ponto ao outro, não é necessário Javascript. Pode criar sua própria regra que altera a posição com [**`@keyframes`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) e aplicar à uma propriedade [**`animation`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/animation):

```css
@keyframes minha-animacao {
  from { background-position: 0 0 }
  to   { background-position: 100% 50% }
}

div {
  animation: minha-animacao 4s linear forwards;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9dbY.jpg) no-repeat;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

#### [Suporte da propriedade `animation`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

Comment: Já agora, se quiser mudar o background.position em tempo real como faço? ou seja está 50px, e mudar até 80 px em tempo real, como se fosse 51px, 52 px, 53 px, 54 px... até chegar aos 80? E que todas esses mudanças se notem no site.

Comment: Faz um loop com Javascript ou então use as animações das CSS.

Comment: Pode-me dar um exemplo por favor, sou um pouco novato

Comment: @Gonçalo Feito, com CSS. Depois, edite sua pergunta e explique que você está buscando alterar a posição do background entre dois pontos. Comentários são descartáveis.